# Insert Input Text After Select Change With Dynamic IDs

Tags: jquery

I've been looking for an answer to this here for the past two days, but nothing seems to stick.

I have a form that dynamically creates inputs with ids basically made up of the param name and each employee's ID through php.

I want to insert a date string in a text input field once the duration select is changed. The page imports jquery-1.12.4.js.

This is the closest I've gotten ... no errors, but nothing happens. 
[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/billOstaski/0o455200/)

```
  <td width="200px">
      <select name="1-duration" id="duration-1">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value=".5">.5 hr</option>
        <option value="1">1 hr</option>
        <option value="1.5">1.5 hrs</option>
        <option value="2">2 hrs</option>
        <option value="2.5">2.5 hrs</option>
        <option value="3">3 hrs</option>
        <option value="3.5">3.5 hrs</option>
        <option value="4">4 hrs</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td width="200px"><input type="text" name="1-promDate" value="" id="promDate-1">
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var employeeID = "1";
        var selectID = "duration-" + employeeID;
        var textID = "promDate-" + employeeID;
        var displayDate = "04/08/2017";
        $("#selectID").change(function(){
          $("#textID").val('displayDate');
        });
      </script>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ids are wrong in your jQuery selectors: "#selectID" should be "#duration-1" and "#textID" should be "#promDate-1". Then the next problem is that you are putting the string displayDate in your input, you probably want to put the variable displayDate, you need to remove the ' surrounding displayDate

Comment: Few problems with that: there are around 20 durations and promdates, not in sequential order, which is why I took this route. Again, these IDs are dynamic, not static. The displayDate is in quotes to fix an "SyntaxError: 08 is not a legal ECMA-262 octal constant." issue.

Comment: I took your suggestion about removing the single quotes surrounding 'displayDate', but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Played with the fiddle, changing the js to

```
    var employeeID = "1";
    var selectID = "#duration-" + employeeID;
    var textID = "#promDate-" + employeeID;
    var displayDate = "04/08/2017";
    $(selectID).change(function(){
      $(textID).val(displayDate);
    });
```

Now it works in the fiddle, but not in my form. I am importing jquery-1.12.4.js and 1.12.1/jquery-ui.js for a datepicker in this form. Could that explain the disconnect?