# Passing PHP Variable to Javascript Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript

This is a followup to [Insert Input Text After Select Change With Dynamic IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282501/insert-input-text-after-select-change-with-dynamic-ids/43284782#43284782) with the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/billOstaski/0o455200/14/)

I've been troubleshooting by creating alerts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var employeeID = <?= json_encode($addTech['employeeID']) ?>;
  var selectID = "#duration-" + employeeID;
  var textID = "#promDate-" + employeeID;
  var displayDate = "<?= $displayDate ?>";
  $(selectID).change(function(){
//       $(textID).val(displayDate);
    try {
      alert(employeeID);
    } catch(err) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
    }
  });
</script>
```

In source, I see the first entry is var employeeID = 1; but when I make a select change, I get 47 in the alert box. There are around 20 employees in this form; all the employeeIDs are correct in source, but the alert returns 47 for them all.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: put the full code please

Comment: if it is not an object, why are you encoding an integer value in first place?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you are getting in php is encoded in JSON. To access it as a JavaScript variable you must decode it:

```
var employeeID = <? echo json_encode($addTech['employeeID']) ?>;
employeeID = JSON.parse(employeeID);
```

However, if `employeeID` is an integer value and not an object you will not need to encode it and can just pass the value directly:

`var employeeID = <? echo $addTech['employeeID'] ?>;`

Comment: I see your point (been at this too long). Thing is, when I use                    var employeeID = <?= $addTech['employeeID'] ?>; I get the correct values in source, but then when I test alert(employeeID); I get 47 for all employees. Also when I test alert(selectID); and alert(textID); I get #duration-47 and promDate-47 respectively for all employees.

Comment: @Bill what data is in `$addTech['employeeID']`? Is it just an integer? Or an object?

Comment: It's just a string.

Comment: @Bill maybe try to call: `json_encode(utf8_encode($addTech['employeeID']))`

Comment: UGH .. no change, still getting that 47 value. Also tried your JSON.parse(employeeID); suggestion with the same results. Thanks for the effort, though, :)

Comment: Going with the int vs string thing, I tried                                                    var employeeID = <?= $addTech['employeeID'] ?>;                     employeeID = employeeID.toString(); ... still getting that 47 value for all employees and I have no idea where it is coming from. The relevant code is in the fiddle, the form code is around 500 lines, so I don't see the point in posting that.

Comment: @Bill Does the number 47 appear in any other part of your code?

Comment: No. It only appears when I call an alert on employeeID, selectID, or textID. I'm thinking maybe 47 represents something in javascript, but I've never come across it before. Maybe I'll just key on employee name instead.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else trying to pass dynamic variables to javascript/JQuery, here's what worked for me:

```
<td width="200px">
      <select class="w3-select" name="<?= $addTech['employeeID'] ?>-duration" id="duration-<?= strval($addTech['employeeID']) ?>">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value=".5">.5 hr</option>
        <option value="1">1 hr</option>
        <option value="1.5">1.5 hrs</option>
        <option value="2">2 hrs</option>
        <option value="2.5">2.5 hrs</option>
        <option value="3">3 hrs</option>
        <option value="3.5">3.5 hrs</option>
        <option value="4">4 hrs</option>
      </select>
</td>
<td width="200px"><input class="w3-input w3-hover-grey" type="text" name="<?= $addTech['employeeID'] ?>-promDate" value="" id="promDate-<?= strval($addTech['employeeID']) ?>">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change', "#duration-<? strval($addTech['employeeID']) ?>", function() {
        var displayDate = "<?= $displayDate ?>";
        $(textID).val(displayDate);
    });
  </script>
</td>
```